# Lemma 31.1 and Exercise 2, Section 31 of Munkres’ Topology

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, separation-axioms

> Show that if $X$ is normal, every pair of disjoint closed sets have neighborhoods whose closures are disjoint.

**Proof:** [Prob. 2, Sec. 31, in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: Any pair of disjoint closed sets in a normal space have neighborhoods whose closures are disjoint](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3264358/861687).

In above proof, we didn’t use $T_1$ separation axiom, by [Munkres Lemma 31.1, no need for $T_1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3447549/861687). So we only need $X$ to be $T_4$. **Am I right?**

> Show that if $X$ is $T_4$, every pair of disjoint closed sets have neighborhoods whose closures are disjoint.

Rephrasing lemma 31.1 to my taste:

> Let $(X, \mathcal{T}_X)$ be a topological space.
>
> (a) $X$ is $T_3$ $\iff$ If $x\in X$ and $U\in \mathcal{N}_x$, then $\exists V\in \mathcal{N}_x$ such that $\overline{V} \subseteq U$.
>
> (b) $X$ is $T_4$ $\iff$ If $A$ is closed in $X$ and $U\in \mathcal{N}_A$, then $\exists V\in \mathcal{N}_A$ such that $\overline{V} \subseteq U$.

Comment: Just normality is needed. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3229996/

Comment: @V.R.M. what definition of normality you’re using?

Comment: X normal $\iff \forall F,G\subseteq X$ closed and $F\cap G=\varnothing, \exists U,V\in\tau: U\cap V=\varnothing, F\subseteq U$ and $G\subseteq V$

Comment: @V.R.M. that means only $T_4$. Munkres’ defined normal space as $T_1$ and $T_4$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to *that* definition ($X$ normal=$X$ is $T_4$ and $T_1$ ), then $X$ just need to be $T_4,$

so doesn't need normality.

However, in Munkres (1975) book, normality is defined  as:

"The space $X$ is said to be **normal** if for each pair $A,B$ of disjoint closed sets of $X,$ there exist disjoint open sets containing $A$ and $B,$ respectively."

rewording:

$∀F,G⊆X$ closed and $F∩G=∅,∃U,V∈τ:U∩V=∅,F⊆U$ and $G⊆V$

Comment: Different books(in this case edition) uses different definition. There’s nothing wrong with that.